# Why does Mittag-Leffler's theorem work over the entire complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, meromorphic-functions

I have a minor factual clarification about the statement of Mittag-Leffler's theorem, and also a more substantive question about its proof.

Q1. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem) on Mittag-Leffler's theorem states that given any closed, discrete set $E$ in an open subset $D \subset \mathbb{C}$, and a desired polynomial in $1/(z-a)$ for each point $a \in E$, there exists a meromorphic function on $D$ with poles at these points, with the corresponding principal parts at each pole. Is there always a meromorphic function on $D$ with poles *only* at the points in $E$? Or are there sometimes necessarily additional poles in $D$ as well?

Q2. The proof outline in the next paragraph starts by taking a straightforward sum of the $p_a(z)$ over finite subsets $F \subset E$. Then it says "While the [partial sums] may not converge as $F$ approaches $E$, one may subtract well-chosen rational functions with poles outside of $D$ (provided by Runge's theorem) without changing the principal parts of [the partial sums] and in such a way that convergence is guaranteed."

Runge's theorem applies to *compact* subsets of $\mathbb{C}$, so this argument makes sense to me when the region $D$ is bounded, and so contained within a compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$. But what if $D$ is the entire complex plane $C$? In that case, if the answer to Q1 is "the former" (as I suspect is the case), then you can't put any poles outside of $D$ because there is nowhere to put them. Let's say you want to put a simple pole at each integer $n$ with residues that blow up ridiculously fast at large $n$, like as the Busy Beaver sequence or something. Then how can you keep the partial sums from diverging?

The only loophole that I can think of is that there is one place "outside of $D = \mathbb{C}$" to put a pole, which is at $\infty$. But the only entire functions with poles at infinity are the polynomials. And I don't see how a polynomial could possibly grow fast enough at large $z$ to subtract off a divergence (and thereby ensure convergence) for a sequence of principal parts that grows really fast.

Comment: We actually do not need Runge in the plane case at least as for any pole $w_n\ne 0$ the Taylor series of the principal part converges to it on the open disc centered at the origin with radius $|w_n|$ and the convergence is absolute  and uniform on the closed disc of radius $|w_n|/2$ so we can truncate it to be within $2^{-n}$ of the principal  part there and since $|w_n| \to \infty$ that will clearly work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to Q1 is no, there is no need no add more poles than required. The reason is because this is always possible by construction, the proof of the theorem is by contructing directly a function satisfying the requirements. Actually the resultant function is defined everywhere, except by the singularities in $E$, so you can actually assume that $D=\mathbb{C}\setminus E$ (if for some reason one is working in a proper domain of $\mathbb{C}$, then one needs just to restrict the original function).

The answer to Q2 is as follows. Suppose $\{h_j(\frac{1}{z-z_j})\}$ are the desired singular parts of the desired meromorphic function, where $h_j$ is a polinomial and $z_j\neq 0$. Assume $|z_j|$ is monotone increasing in $j$. Let $D_j = D(0,|z_j|/2)$ and choose a polinomial $f_j$ (Runge theorem allows to assume this when the complement of the compact set is connected, if you take a rational function it may add extra singularities outside $E$, so this is in fact important) such that
$$|h_j(\frac{1}{z-z_j})-f_j(z)|\leq  \frac{1}{j^2},$$
for $z\in D(0,|z_j|/2)$. Fix an $r>0$ arbitrary and let $z\in D(0,r)\setminus \{z_j\}$, then eventually the series $\sum_{j\geq 1} h_j(\frac{1}{z-z_j})-f_j(z)$ is dominated by a series of the form $\sum \frac{1}{j^2}$, and therefore we have absolute and uniform convergence. Hence $f(z) = \sum_{j\geq 1} h_j(\frac{1}{z-z_j})-f_j(z)$ is the desired meromorphic function (it converges in $D(0,r)\setminus \{z_j\}$ for any $r>0$). However, we assumed $z_j\neq 0$, so if originally you wanted also a singularity at the origin, it suffices just to add the desired singular part at this point to the constructed $f$.

Comment: Just so I have the picture right in my mind: the idea is that you add the desired poles one by one in order of increasing distance from 0 - but with each new pole that you add, you also subtract off a polynomial that better and better approximates the new pole's contribution to a growing disk about the origin (always small enough to exclude the latest pole, but growing without bound). These polynomial approximations are good enough to keep the error small enough to guarantee convergence everywhere except for at the desired poles. Presumably as you get to farther- and farther-away poles,

Comment: the polynomial needs to go to higher and higher order to approximately cancel off that pole's contribution near 0, but that order is always finite for each pole. Brilliant, thanks. The piece that I was missing is that you can (approximately) cancel each new pole with a new polynomial one by one as you go - you don't need to first add up all of the poles and then try to cancel them out all at once at the end.

Comment: So it would be a nice exercise for you to show that the series $\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{1}{z-n} + \frac{1}{n}$ defines a meromorphic function (which arises contructing it as I said above), you only need to check that by neglecting enoughly initial terms, the series converges absolutely and uniformly on compact sets which do not contain any integer (note that in this case we are only taking the first term of each Taylor series!).

Comment: I'm adding the next comment again, since it needed to be fixed: You have the right picture. The last thing you said, about the order of the polynomial going higher, is intuitively expectable, but is not necessary. For this, as Conrad said in the comments, you can construct the polynomial by expanding $h(\frac{1}{z−j})$ in Taylor series at the origin, since $|z_j|>0$, and truncate it, say at a polynomial $P_j$ assuring that $|h(\frac{1}{z−j})-P_j(z)|<\frac{1}{j^2}$ for $|z|$ in $D(0,r_j)$ with $r_j$ probably less than $|z_j|/2$ but also satisfying $r_j \rightarrow \infty$.